# Fetch Last Login Details using Summarize by Time Stamp in KQL

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I am trying to get last login details of user in Kusto database using KQL query language. However I am not getting exact result with below query.

GlobalID - Unique GUID Value which will be created every time user logged in

UserId - Logged in UserId value

LastSuccessFullLoginTimeStamp - Max Timestamp value

```
 //Fetch Last Logged in userID details
 let window = 2h;
 Events
 | where Timestamp >= ago(window)
 | extend UserId = tostring(Properties.UserId)
 | where UserId in ('12345','56789','24680')
 //| summarize LastSuccessFullLoginTimeStamp = max(Timestamp), count() by 
  GlobalId,UserId
  |project GlobalID,UserId,TimeStamp
```

[image]

But I am failed to get output as like below from above sample data. **Fetch latest GlobalID based on userId and last logged in time.** Where I am doing wrong? I tried with summarize, make_set but in vain.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the arg_max() function:

```
 let window = 2h;
 Events
 | where Timestamp >= ago(window)
 | extend UserId = tostring(Properties.UserId)
 | where UserId in ('12345','56789','24680')
 | summarize arg_max(Timestamp, *) by UserId
```