# Azure Log Analytics for Postgres Flexible Server

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-log-analytics

Just trying to use a pre-existing "Slowest queries - top 5" from Azure log analytics for postgres flexible server.  The query that is provided is:

```
// Slowest queries 
// Identify top 5 slowest queries. 
AzureDiagnostics
| where ResourceProvider == "MICROSOFT.DBFORPOSTGRESQL"
| where Category == "QueryStoreRuntimeStatistics"
| where user_id_s != "10" //exclude azure system user
| summarize avg(todouble(mean_time_s)) by event_class_s , db_id_s ,query_id_s
| top 5 by avg_mean_time_s desc
```

This query results in the error :

'where' operator: Failed to resolve column or scalar expression named 'user_id_s'
If the issue persists, please open a support ticket. Request id: XXXX

I am guessing that something is not configured in order to utilize the user_id_s column.  Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: can you check whether the value inside the column `user_id_s` is string or an integer. if it is an integer try removing the `double quotes` to the value

Comment: Some additional information, it seems the column user_id_s is not available to use.  when I comment out the line - | where user_id_s != "10" //exclude azure system user, then I get the error:  
'summarize' operator: Failed to resolve scalar expression named 'event_class_s'
If the issue persists, please open a support ticket.

Answer (score -1):

I am expecting you are checking the integer value **10** is not equal to the **user_id_s**.
In your KQL query **`user_id_s != "10"`** .

Thanks @ [venkateshdodda-msft](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15968720/venkateshdodda-msft) I am adding your suggestion to help to fix the issue.

If you are using **integer** in a KQL make sure to ***remove*** the **" "** ***double quotes***.

```sql
# using as a integer
| where user_id_s !=  10
```

Or **convert the integer into string** by using

```sql
# converting into string
 | extend user_id_s = tostring(Properties.user_id_s)
 | where UserId in ('10')
```

#### Modified KQL Query

```sql
AzureDiagnostics
| where ResourceProvider == "MICROSOFT.DBFORPOSTGRESQL"
| where Category == "QueryStoreRuntimeStatistics"
# using as a integer
| where user_id_s != 10 //exclude azure system user
| summarize avg(todouble(mean_time_s)) by event_class_s , db_id_s ,query_id_s
| top 5 by avg_mean_time_s desc
```

#### Reference:

1. [Operator failed to resolve table or column expression](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-observability/where-operator-failed-to-resolve-table-or-column-expression/m-p/241234)
2. [Converting integer to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71477696/fetch-last-login-details-using-summarize-by-time-stamp-in-kql)

Comment: it does not seem to be a data type issue.  Some additional information, it seems the column user_id_s is not available to use.  when I comment out the line - | where user_id_s != "10" //exclude azure system user, then I get the error:  
'summarize' operator: Failed to resolve scalar expression named 'event_class_s'
If the issue persists, please open a support ticket.  Is seems all of the columns with an "_s" are not available.

Comment: It seems all of the columns that end in "_s" are not available.  It really seems like something is not configured.  Perhaps I need to install a Diagnostic Setting.  Just fishing for a solution at this point.